# Maintain space between bars regardless of sample numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make several plots same space interval between bars regardless of sample numbers

As described below.

[image]

Not like this

[image]

My original script is

```
myData <- read.csv('L1L2_100percent.csv', header = T, sep =',')

ggplot(data = myData, aes(x = region, y = vaf, fill = type)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4) +
 coord_flip()
```

I think it has to do with saving pictures with a specific height, but I think the height
has to be determined with sample numbers but I don't know the exact value.

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible data? Easiest way is the `dput()` Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust the height of the plot on saving proportional to the number of bars.
Here, `plt1` has 5 instead of 10 bars thus it should be saved with a height that is only half than those of `plt2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create example data
myData <-
  iris %>% transmute(
    region = row_number() %% 20,
    vaf = Sepal.Length,
    type = Species
  )

plt1 <-
  myData %>%
  filter(region < 5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = region, y = vaf, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

plt2 <-
  myData %>%
  filter(region < 10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = region, y = vaf, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()

ggsave("plt1.png", plt1, height = plt1$data$region %>% unique() %>% length())
ggsave("plt2.png", plt2, height = plt2$data$region %>% unique() %>% length())
```

Plt1:
[image]

Plt2:
[image]